# Компиляция ядра ALt Linux

Tags: altlinux, linux

Не знаю, насколько этот вопрос тут может быть обсуждаем. Но у меня с компиляцией ядра возникла одна проблемка (и решаться она ни в какую не желает) Ядро упорно создается размеров больше стандартного. Я уже и поотключал все что посчитал ненужным. И в модули повыносил все, что может быть нужным. И дебагов явно нет.  Размер ядра слегка уменьшился, но по-прежнему продолжает оставаться в пределах 3-х с лишним мег (со стрипом, последнее ядро вышло в 2,5 мега. Сравните со стандартным - 2,1 мб). Естественно. я такое ядро поставить не могу - lilo ругается, говорит, шибко большое.

- make mrproper для очистки не забываю.
- Опции компиляции CFLAGS='-O2 -march=native -fomit-frame-pointer'
- А вот как приложить сам конфиг ядра сюда - я не знаю. Просто в текст кинуть - будет огромная портянка.

Однажды даже всю папку сносил, разворачивал заново. Все равно с теми же конфигами выходит тот же результат... 3-4 мега ядра :(  Ничего понять не могу...

Comment: Для архива: http://altlinux.org/KernelBuild (вкратце -- этого всё-таки не требуется, lilo вполне работает со штатным ядром; см., например, [стартеркит](http://altlinux.org/starterkits) jeos).

Answer (score 1):

На выходе  получается vmlinux  или vmlinuz. Если vmlinux можно попробовать сжать при компиляции. make bzlilo.

Comment: Ну, насколько я понимаю, make само уже создает vmlinux, сжатое алгоритму который был задан в файле конфигурации.

Comment: Могу ошибаться, но раньше make создавал ядро без сжатия.

Comment: Так оно и оказалось... :( сбила с толку схожесть наименований vmlinux и vmlinuz. Кроме того само сжатое bZimage оказалось засунуто вглубь дерева и поискать его раньше мозги не дошли...